# Java console not closing

Tags: java, ide

I am new to Java so I am figuring out some basics. When I run this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int myInt = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println(myInt);
    }
}
```

I was expecting project to end after `myInt` is printed on the screen, but console stays frozen. I can't run this project again if I don't make at least one change in code.
I would expect project to end automatically with possibility to run this project as many times as I want to (as I am used to it from other languages).
Is there some mistake I didn't see in code or is this something I just need to get used to?

Comment: You need to call `scan.close()` before your method terminates.

Comment: @jsheeran no, you don't. You just need to make sure that stdin has a value to read. [This terminates just fine](http://ideone.com/tXdogW).

Comment: Which ide are you using or you are compiling using command promt

Comment: Apologies if that was unclear - meant "otherwise you'll have issues when running it again" instead of "otherwise it won't terminate". Having said that, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using eclipse neon 3.  
And is it normal that after i run the project, i need to click into console? Shouldn't that be automatically?